# How to optimize MySQL query when field values are not distinct

Tags: mysql, indexing

Suppose I have a MySQL table, with a indexed field called balance. However, the table contains 95% of rows with balance = 0. So if I was to go:

```
Select * from mytable where balance > 0.02
```

the query would take quite a while, if the table had 1mil+ rows, as the BTree index does not have a distinct set of values for balance.

In this situation, without changing the data, how would one optimize the SQL query

Comment: Did you try that - my guess is that it is fast no matter the values.

Comment: I tried it on a similar table, which only had 2 rows where balance > 0. Took 2 seconds on a 1mil row table (slow)

Comment: Have you tried setting balance to NULL and only setting a value if <> 0?

Comment: that is a good idea, but it doesn't appear to help

Comment: Just tested: 10 rows out of 1M are returned in zero time. So you need to give us more info about how to reproduce the long runtime. You didn't even post an EXPLAIN result.

Comment: I think it is the way the data is inserted, but the BTree index is the problem, I think

Answer (score 3):

First, your query is likely to be returning a lot of rows.  That is going to take time.

If you only need a few, you can add `limit`:

```
Select *
from mytable
where balance > 0.02
limit 100;
```

Second, if you have any particularly large columns, then those could dominate the time for returning rows.  If this is an issue, then select only the columns you really need.

Third, an index might help.  If very few rows satisfy the `where` clause then an index on `balance` should speed the query.  However, if a lot of rows match the filter condition, then you are returning a lot of data -- and that can take time.

Also, this assumes that something called `mytable` is really a table.  If it is a view, then all bets are off.  You need to optimize the view and not the query.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all of that. I think it is slow because the 95% duplicate field values does not give the BTree index much to work with

Comment: @OoDee . . . If this is really important, you could make that column the first key in a clustered index.

Comment: `LIMIT 99999999` might trick the Optimizer into using `INDEX(balance)` regardless.

Answer (score 2):

This is a radical approach, but if this query is very critical you could add a partition to the table in the balance field:

EDIT: For some reason MySQL partition are restricted to INT values, maybe this workaround will work:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
PARTITION BY RANGE( CEILING(balance) ) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (1),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

NOTE: This approach will only work if balance is declared as a Decimal type, not a Float type.

Comment: I get an error saying "VALUES value for partition" ... "must have type INT"